# Unable to persist data using Gorilla Sessions on subsequent requests to server

Tags: session, go, gorilla

I've read all the related questions regarding this and still can't manage to get it working.

I am using Chi router and Gorilla Sessions.

First I init the `store.Options`:

```
var authKey = []byte("somesecret")
// Encryption Key
var encKey = []byte("someothersecrets")
var store = sessions.NewCookieStore(authKey, encKey)

func init() {
    fmt.Println("$$$%%$$%%%%%%")
    store.Options = &sessions.Options{
    Domain:   "localhost",
    Path:     "/",
    MaxAge:   3600 * 8, // 8 hours
    HttpOnly: true,
}
```

Then when the first route handler is hit, I generate a new `state` variable and save it to the session:

```
session, err = store.Get(r, "my_cookie")
session.Values["state"] = newState
errSave := session.Save(r, w)
```

This saves without error. Next the client does some stuff and hits a different route handler where I try to grab that `state` variable out of the session:

```
session, err = store.Get(r, "my_cookie")
existingState := session.Values["state"]
```

However this existing state value is always nil, the `session.IsNew` always returns true here as well.

I've managed to solve it by making `session` a global defined variable and not re-calling

```
 session, err = store.Get(r, "my_cookie")
```

in the second handler but this seems like the wrong approach. It *seems* like since I am calling `store.get()` with a different request object each time that it is creating a new store but this seems completely contradictory to the purpose of this library. Can anyone shed light on what I'm missing here?

Comment: can you share your client code? Maybe the issue is about the async client perform the second action before the cookie stored at first place.

Comment: Have you checked that the client actually submits `my_cookie` with the second request?

Comment: @nvcnvn The first request generates an OAuth URL for the client, the client then clicks the link, authorizes the service, and is redirected back at which point the second request is made so I don't believe it is a sync problem.

Comment: @VasiliyFaronov The client doesn't submit `my_cookie` it is hardcoded on the server inside the second request handler. It is just a way to grab the `store` which has saved the `state` variable

Comment: @pat Why do you think it has the word “cookie” all over? It round-trips session state inside an HTTP cookie, which is [set on `w`, under the given `name`, when you call `Save`](https://github.com/gorilla/sessions/blob/12bd4761fc66ac946e16fcc2a32b1e0b066f6177/store.go#L109). If the client doesn’t submit this cookie on subsequent requests, maybe your `sessions.Options` are wrong. Does the client request you at `http://localhost/`?

Comment: @VasiliyFaronov Interesting maybe I'm slightly confused on how it works. I thought `my_cookie` was simply a key used to fetch that particular session. The client does request at `localhost`. Should `my_cookie` be replaced with some parameter sent by the client? I guess that makes more sense so the server can distinguish one session from another? What would be the best thing from the client to use for that key?

Comment: @VasiliyFaronov but even so you would think if it was hardcoded for that 1 user it would definitely work since it's definitely the same session?

Comment: “I thought `my_cookie` was simply a key used to fetch that particular session” — exactly, but it is fetched from the *header submitted with the HTTP request*. All session state is stored on the client and submitted with every request.

Comment: There are other approaches — for example, the [`FilesystemStore`](https://godoc.org/github.com/gorilla/sessions#FilesystemStore) saves session state to your server’s file system — but it *still uses cookies* to know which request corresponds to which session. Multiple users (= multiple sessions) can interact with your server in parallel, and the only general way to associate a request with a session is through an HTTP cookie.

Comment: Yes that makes a lot of sense, but that's why I thought store already takes `r` the `http.Request` object and then that `my_cookie` is just an additional param in case you wanted to have multiple sessions for the same request.